# Dynamic text in master page of Birt report

Tags: expression, birt

Can dynamic text be entered into a header or footer of a master page?

I have placed dynamic text into a grid which then sits in the master page footer, this doesn't work and gives error:

```
ReportDesign (id = 1):
+ Invalid javascript expression: ReferenceError: "row" is not defined. (<inline>#1)
```

When I test the expression in the footer of the report layout itself this works.

Please see the expression below:

```
if( BirtComp.lessOrEqual( row["Aggregation"], "1,500.00" )){"user1.jpg"} 
else if (BirtComp.greaterThan(row["Aggregation"], "1,500.00")){ "user2.jpg"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use dynamic text in the master page is as follows:

- Optional, but recommended: Create a dataset "MasterPage" which selects the dynamic data that you need.
- Create a grid in the page footer (and/or header) of the master page.
- Bind the grid to the dataset "MasterPage".
- Use dynamic text items and data items inside the grid as you like.

Important:

- The grid uses only the first row returned by your dataset.
- Thus, it is best practice to create the dataset in such a way that it will return exactly one row.
- This means that BIRT aggregation functions won't work here.
- If your "MasterPage" dataset is JDBC based, you can of course use SQL aggregation functions like SUM, COUNT etc.
- It is not possible to access "the current first record for the current page" this way: The "MasterPage" dataset returns one record for the whole report.

Comment: Thank you, it's frustrating to find you cannot use aggregation within a MasterPage and also frustrating that a grid will only show the first row. I will have to use a method of row spacing within a regular report footer instead, so the row appears at the bottom of the page.